# Pause QEMU/KVM VM (save RAM and CPU state to disk) like vmware Player?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

Is it possible to save the state of a virtual machine under QEMU/KVM/libvirt (on x86-64) to disk like you can on vmware Player, that means:

- The RAM and CPU/system state is save to disk
- The OS is stopped from the outside (no suspend to disk within the VM)
- The VM can be continued after rebooting the host?

If it is possible, would it need special drivers within the VM?  Which one for Linux and Windows 7 guests?

Comment: `virsh` knows the commands `suspend`, `dompmsuspend` and `managedsave` for different tasks (see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/sect-Managing_guest_virtual_machines_with_virsh-Shutting_down_rebooting_and_force_shutdown_of_a_guest_virtual_machine.html)

Comment: specifically `managedsave` is the one which meets these requirements

Comment: I am new to qemu, but doesn't [savevm](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor#savevm) do what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `virt-manager` window has a feature "shut down" -> "save".

Additional drivers are not required.  I think the obvious bad thing happens with system time inside the guest.  I don't know if there are guest drivers available to let the clock catch up.

Comment: So it has. Thanks very much, had not spotted it. For everyone who is interested, this needs space in `/home/$USER/.config/libvirt/qemu/save` which may be a link to a folder on a larger disk if needed.

Answer (score 11):

To achieve the same thing as VMmware's "Suspend" in `virsh`, do:

```
virsh managedsave <domain-name>
```

The machine can later be resumed with

```
virsh start <domain-name>
```

On my tested host (Ubuntu Server 14.04), the save file is stored at:

```
/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/save/<domain-name>.save
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the command line equivalent of the accepted answer and useful as an addition.

Answer (score 5):

The Red Hat Virtualization Deployment and Administration Guide [has a section on this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/sect-Managing_guest_virtual_machines_with_virsh-Shutting_down_rebooting_and_force_shutdown_of_a_guest_virtual_machine.html), but if you don't have access then it wont be much help...

In a nutshell, what you are looking for is the `virsh dompmsuspend` command and option. The GUI utilities for KVM are okay but leave a **LOT** of functionality out. The `virsh` command can do anything you need it to, given the right options and parameters. I am not familiar with 'suspending' a KVM guest, so I can't really give you much guidance, but the [documentation](http://libvirt.org/virshcmdref.html) should have everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's what @ridgy suggested (and @sourcejedi detailed in its comment). Used `virt-manager` for the moment but shall try this out in the beloved command line, as well.