# How to save the machine state of a QEMU VM started using qemu-system-x86_64?

Tags: qemu

I have a VM running using:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 8192 -smp 3 \
  -net user -net nic,model=virtio -boot menu=on \
  -drive file=guixsd-usb-install-0.13.0.x86_64-linux \
  -drive file=guixsd.img
```

per the [GuixSD VM installation guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/html_node/Installing-GuixSD-in-a-VM.html) (with some slight modifications like the RAM usage, file names and CPU cores allocated). I would like to save the machine state so that I can restore it later (exactly as it was before I saved it, right in the middle of running the `guix system init ...` command. Sort of the equivalent to the "Save the machine state" option for VirtualBox VMs. I saw this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361015/27613 but it requires the name of the VM, running `virsh list --all` doesn't list the name of VMs started via this command. DuckDuckGo searching for answers hasn't revealed anything as most results related to if I had started the VM from virt-manager.

Comment: [answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1156020/613775)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your qemu displays a window. If this is the case, press `ctrl-alt-2` to switch to the monitor interface (and `ctrl-alt-1` to get back).

You should see the (qemu) prompt, now you can type in the following commands

- `loadvm <snapshot name>`
- `savevm <snapshot name>`
- `delvm <snapshot name>`
- `info snapshots`

While qemu is not running, you can list the saved states with `qemu-img snapshot -l guix.img`.

You can load a snapshot directly when starting qemu by adding the switch

> `-loadvm <snapshot name>`

to the command line.

For more convenient access to the monitor interface, add the directive

> `-monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:1234,server,nowait`

to the command line. You can then use `telnet localhost 1234` to talk to qemu. Caveat: do not enter `q` or `quit` to get out of there, this will cause the emulator to shut down! Press `ctrl-]` instead and *then* type `q`.